# Replace a character only if preceded by a digit

Tags: text-processing, sed

Suppose I have a file containing

```
abcxd,abcx,6000/600x1
```

I need to replace the `x` to `*` which has a number in front of it. I tried

```
sed 's/[0-9]x/*/g'
```

but it is wrong as expected output is:

```
abcxd,abcx,6000/600*1
```

Answer (score 4):

Use capture groups and back-reference

```
$ echo 'abcxd,abcx,6000/600x1' | sed 's/\([0-9]\)x/\1*/g'
abcxd,abcx,6000/600*1
```

- `\([0-9]\)` capture this digit so that it can be referenced `\1`

  - See [Capture Groups](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions) for some more discussion on this regex usage
- With ERE, syntax would be `sed -E 's/([0-9])x/\1*/g'`
- use `g` modifier if there are multiple matches to be replaced

With regex flavors like `pcre`, one can use [lookarounds](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns)

```
$ echo 'abcxd,abcx,6000/600x1' | perl -pe 's/\d\Kx/*/g'
abcxd,abcx,6000/600*1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ echo "abcxd,abcx,6000/600x1" |\
sed -E 's/^([a-z,]*)([0-9\/]*)(x)(.*$)/\1\2*\4/'
```